# .Net Standard 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.1 Jenkins Build errors

Tags: jenkins, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .Net Framework 4.7.1 Project that Imports a class library that is also .Net Framework 4.7.1. The class library references a nuget class library that is .Net Standard 2.0.

The project builds perfectly in visual studio. However the Jenkins build give the following error

```
Package PackageName 1.0.0 is not compatible with net471 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1). Package PackageName 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

I have read an [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx) which suggested that the issue was the project restore style so I added the following to the .cspoj files.

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

This is fails to build in Jenkins. Is there a step I am missing?